# WPF ListBox scrolls to top when I change status message or show wait screen

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll

I'm developing an opensource application named [Media Assistant](http://mediaassistant.codeplex.com/). I used a ListBox to show the library. ItemsSource is bound to a list of LibraryItem. Here is the XALM.

```
<ListBox Name="Tree" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource.OrderedLibraryItems}" 
    Background="{StaticResource LibraryBackground}"
    Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    BorderThickness="0"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListLibraryItemTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    MouseDoubleClick="HandleMouseDoubleClick"
/>
```

The problem is when I show any status message at the bottom of my window from a thread by using Dispatcher.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,new ParameterizedThreadStart(action), state);
```

The ListBox scrolls to at the top. If I don't show any status message then it works just fine. The datacontext or list items or focus has not been changed. I could not found any reason why it's doing that. It happens when I display any wait screen which is a non modal window. I could not recreate it in a different project. [Here](http://mediaassistant.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/8705#) is the source code of Media Assistant. 
You can easily re-create it by un-commenting the return statement of method SetStatusMessage at BackgroundScanner class.

Comment: I had something similar and all I can figure is the UI wanted the selected Item in view.  If the index was -1  then it tried to show 0.  I was not using a Dispatcher message but if I put the TextBlock above the ListBox I had better luck but never got it working all the way.  With a ListView I got better behavior.   ListBox is fast and I sill like it but is does some stuff I have not figured out.  Without deferred scrolling  do you get the same behavior?  If your binding mode is oneway then declare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason behind this, so the solution. 
I used a DockPanel to layout my UI. I put my status bar at the bottom, the ListBox on the Left and other items are on middle and top. There is a TextBlock in my StatusBar which has width and Height set to Auto. So, when I changed text of my StatusBar TextBlock it's width and height gets recalculated and It's parent's recalculates it's layout. Hence the ListBox gets invoked to Measures and Arrange. Even though it's size does not gets changed it resets it's scroll position to top. It happens only if I use ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" at the ListBox. By default it is True. So, even though I did not set this value It was resetting the scroll position. If I disable it by using ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" then it works fine.

```
<ListBox Name="Tree" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource.OrderedLibraryItems}" 
    Background="{StaticResource LibraryBackground}"
    Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    BorderThickness="0"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListLibraryItemTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    MouseDoubleClick="HandleMouseDoubleClick"
/>
```

But setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" disables virtualization and I want to use virtualization to my ListBox so I set fixed Height and Width to the TextBlock. So, the DockPanel does not re-arrange it's children if I change the status message.

May be it's a bug at ScrollViewer. It should not change the scroll position if the size has not changed.

Comment: Your answer is a workaround. It means there is no proven explanation and this solution might not fit for everyone. Could you uncheck the "answer resolves question" flag so that people can still post a real solution? I've got the same problem and fixing dimensions is not possible for my app.

Comment: If the "solution" works for the poster they should check it.  Other users may wish to provide better (i.e. "real fix" in this case) answers and upvite better solutions but that is how SO works I think.  I have one case where my answer has 5 upvotes even though the "correct, checked" answer only had one :)  Maybe I'm wrong about how this works buyt that's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.Items.GetItemAt(listBox1.Items.Count - 1));
```

Comment: Your code makes the ListBox's ScrollViewer scroll to the last item. I would like the scrollviewer to stay at the previous position (which can be from zero to N-1.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to @user904627's answer, here is an enhanced version of his **workaround**. The issue with just fixing `Width` and `Height` is the ListBox keeps the same position even if the user resizes the Window. This is not acceptable.

This is why I created this tiny behavior which fixes Width and Height **but** listens to the parent element's `SizeChanged` event to let the ListBox resize itself when the container's size changes.

The code is here: [VirtualizedListBoxFixBehavior](http://codepaste.net/ko64e5)

When the parent element is resized, I restore `Width` and `Height` to `double.NaN` (so the control can resize itself) and I queue the bit of code which fixes the size properties to actual values in the `Dispatcher` for later execution.

*But this still is an ugly working workaround...*

Answer (score -1):

Since the layout is being reset, it is expected that the list box to select the first item (0).

Can you try to set the selected item to the number of existing items in the list box:

```
Tree.SelectedIndex = Tree.Items.Count;
```

I did not test this solution on your code but I have used it in another project of mine where I had a similar problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. WPF is not really selecting the first item when the resize occurs: it's just resetting the scrollviewer Vertical and Horizontal Offsets. When the problem occurs, I don't want to change the user's selection but prevent the scrollviewer from resetting to zero. I'm sorry but your solution has unwanted side-effects (changing selection).

Comment: My mistake, I understood it badly. To prevent the side effect the selected items array can be stored and reseted after "refresh" occurs. Anyway it is not the solution to the problem.